# Issues with Application.Onkey

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked at about every article/question on this issue that I've been able to find, but no luck -- thanks in advance for your help:

In my "This Workbook," I have the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnKey "+^%{+}", "Insert_Columns"
End Sub
```

In a Module, I have the following:

```
Sub Insert_Columns()

Dim num As String

num = InputBox("How many columns do you want to insert?")

If num <> "" Then
    If num > 0 Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, num).EntireColumn.Insert
End If

End Sub
```

For some reason, the shortcut is not working. I've tried many variations of this, but does anyone have an idea why the shortcut would not be working? The macro runs great if I click "Run" manually.

Thank you!

Comment: First of all you don't need the first `+`, you can simply have `"^%{+}"`. Second, to access the `+` character you need to press the `Shift` key (in most standard keyboards, `+` is on the `=` button), what this means is that you need to press `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+=` to run the procedure. If you don't want to press the `Shift` key, then use `"^%{=}"`

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Also found that a macro program I was using had a conflicting shortcut. 

I'm trying to mark this as the answer, but don't see the option to do so since it's a comment — please let me know if I'm missing something, and thanks again!

Comment: Great! Ok, I will write an answer since it solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** of all you don't need the first `+`, you can simply have `"^%{+}"`.

**Second**, to access the `+` character you need to press the `Shift` key (in most standard keyboards, `+` is on the `=` button), what this means is that you need to press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`=` to run the procedure. If you don't want to press the `Shift` key, then use `"^%{=}"`

**Aside:**

You may want to place these `OnKey` settings in `Workbook_Activate` and reset them in `Workbook_Deactivate`. This avoid running these procedures when the workbook is closed or it is not the active one. Please note how I fully qualified the procedure name to avoid a conflict with another procedure that may have the same name in a different open workbook.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
  '* Set OnKey shortcuts
  Application.OnKey Key:="^%{=}", Procedure:=ThisWorkbook.Name & "!Insert_Columns"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
  '* Reset OnKey shortcuts
  Application.OnKey Key:="^%{=}", Procedure:=""
End Sub
```

A final thing to consider is using `Application.InputBox` rather than `InputBox` as the former gives you more control over what the user enters. Find docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox).

```vb
Sub Insert_Columns()

  Dim num As String
  
  '* Type:=1 -> Number
  num = Application.InputBox("How many columns do you want to insert?", Type:=1)
  
  '* Application.InputBox returns False if x or Cancel buttons are pressed
  If num Then
      If num > 0 Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, num).EntireColumn.Insert
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

mmmm well i had tested your code and run but maybe you try to use `Ctrl + Alt + Shif + {+}` but you are pressing {NUMPAD+} remenber {+} and {NUMPAD+} are keys differents when i press {+} code run well [image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! I wanted it to be the normal + keyboard key (not the numpad key), but I appreciate your answer. For others who find this post — if you want to use the numpad "+" sign, you put {107} as the key to use.