# Application.OnKey doesn't work problem with right module for it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have same problem like the one descibe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047703/issues-with-application-onkey) but answer there doesn't help me. Shortcut doesn't work but if I click "Run" manually everything works.

My problem may be due to the fact that I wrote the macro itself elsewhere and after testing it, copied it to a file where I could use it.
The file has 11 sheets (12 if I count ThisWorkbook) and 12 modules.
I only want the macro and thus also shortcut key to work in the sheet called Data, but I don't actually know where exactly to copy the code. I am new to VBA. Thank you all for your help.

Here is the code I have so far.

Shortcut key:

```
Sub MacroShortcut()
 Applicaton.OnKey Key:="+^{I}", Procedure:=ThisWorkbook.Name & "CopyOnlyVisibleRowsInColumnsG_I_T"
End Sub
```

Macro I want to run by Shortcut:

```
Sub CopyOnlyVisibleRowsInColumnsG_I_T()
'
' CopyOnlyVisibleRowsInColumnsG_I_T Macro
' Copy only visible rows in columns G, I, T into a new file and add no. 5 into last column.
'
' Shortcut key: Ctrl+Shift+I
'
    Dim startWs As Worksheet
    Dim endFile As Workbook
    Dim endWs As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowColB As Long
    Dim lastRowColG As Long

    Set startWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    Set endFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user_name\OneDrive\import.txt")

    Set endWs = Worksheets("import")

    'clear all content in target workbook
    Cells.ClearContents

    'set last row in column G
    lastRowColG = startWs.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    startWs.Range("G1:G" & lastRowColG).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=endWs.Range("B:B")
    startWs.Range("I1:I" & lastRowColG).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=endWs.Range("A:A")
    startWs.Range("T1:T" & lastRowColG).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=endWs.Range("C:C")
    startWs.Range("T1:T" & lastRowColG).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=endWs.Range("D:D")

    'convert text format to date format for columns C and D
    endWs.Range("C:C, D:D").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"

    'delete header from new worksheet
    endWs.Range("A1:E1").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete

    'adds 5 to column E according to the number of rows in column B
    lastRowColB = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("E1:E" & lastRowColB).Value = 5

    'save new file
    endFile.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Try it like this `Procedure:="'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!CopyOnlyVisibleRowsInColumnsG_I_T"`.

Answer (score 0):

If your macro is in a standard module, you can simply use a name of this macro. You even don't need a special procedure to activate this shortcut. You can use a macro option to define it. However special procedure will also work.
[image: Shortcut]

If your macro is in an object module e.g. worksheet you should add the codename of this sheet and dot before the name of the macro.

```
Applicaton.OnKey Key:="+^{I}", Procedure:=Worksheets("Data").Codename & ".CopyOnlyVisibleRowsInColumnsG_I_T"
```

It's simpler to use the codename name as it is but I don't know it. E.g.

```
Applicaton.OnKey Key:="+^{I}", Procedure:="Sheet3.CopyOnlyVisibleRowsInColumnsG_I_T"
```

But in any case your macro may be called from any sheet.
If you want your macro to be active only in one sheet you must add a code at the beginning of your macro to check if Activesheet is your sheet and if not, Exit Sub.

Comment: Well, I deleted MacroShortcut Sub and tried add shortcut via Macro Options window. Now if I run macro using this shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+I) my macro doesn' work properly. For some reason it just open import.txt without changes but if I run macro manualy everything works as expected and I have no idea why.

Comment: You should insert a Breakpoint at the beginning of the code of your routine (on the first statement) and test it step by step (F8) in both variants, then compare what happens.

Comment: It looks like if I run macro using (Ctrl+Shift+I) shortcut then macro ends on this line `Set endFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user_name\OneDrive\import.txt")` so it really just open file but code after isn't execute. If i run macro without using shortcut everything works as it should.

Comment: Don't get any error message? The code stops before `Set endWs = Worksheets("import")` and `ClearContents` is not executed ?
I tried to run this macro (without data manipulation, only opening and saving the file) and it works for me in both cases.

Comment: The problem, as I found out, was the use of the `Open` method and the `Shift key` (Shift key makes a vb script stop at any `Open` statement, VBA bug). So now I have to use the `Add` method instead of `Open` and modify the code to work correctly. Because overriding `Open` to `Add` in the existing code will change the behavior of saving the txt file in a way I don't want it to work.

Comment: This problem with a `Shift` key seems to be specific to your configuration. I don't notice anything like that in myself. Isn't it possible to use another key combination without `Shift`?

Comment: Then you are probably lucky (or is your excel version?). Anyway I found those discussions where people had same problem [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409524/excel-vba-macro-hangs-after-opening-a-document-when-run-via-shortcut-key-but-r), [spreadsheet1](https://www.spreadsheet1.com/excel-vba-bugs.html), [jkp ads](https://jkp-ads.com/articles/workbookopenbug.asp) but all are rather old, I admit. And combination without `Shift`, well, excel have so many shortcuts so I'm not sure, which isn't used. Now I just must modify my code in order to work properly with `Add` method.

Comment: My Excel version is 365 (Windows 10, 64 bit). There are many predefined key combinations, but not always all of them are used. I think e.g. `Ctrl+q` is not typically used.

Comment: We have same Excel version, but I have Win 11 if this bug occurs because of that, I have no idea. But I have to edit the code anyway because I have to move it to PERSONAL.XLSB I can't add it to directly to file, when I need to use it. I can't edit this file as freely as i would like to (because it's a file we use at work not my personal one).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to add a space

```
Sub MacroShortcut()
Applicaton.OnKey Key:="+^{I}", Procedure:=ThisWorkbook.Name & " CopyOnlyVisibleRowsInColumnsG_I_T"
End Sub
```